# How do you get daterangepicker input passed into django form?

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, daterangepicker

I am almost completely new to Django and web development so please help me out. I pretty much just want to create a form on Django that takes in two dates(a start and end date) and a text input. I have tried everything to get daterangepicker into my program but I either get the daterangepicker to show up but unable to pass the html input back into the form or I can't get the daterangepicker to show up. Basically, I just want to allow the users to pick the two dates using a calendar instead so I guess I don't need to implement daterangepicker if it is not necessary. Here is what I have so far:

views.py

```
from .forms import HyugaRequestForm

def create_req(request):
    name = request.user.username
    form = HyugaRequestForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        instance.name = name
        instance.s_date = form.cleaned_data.get('Start_Date')
        instance.e_date = form.cleaned_data.get('End_Date')
        instance.save()
    context = {'form':form,}
    return render(request,'timeline/hyuga_requests_form.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Hyuga_Requests
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.extras import SelectDateWidget

class HyugaRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Start_Date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
    End_Date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Hyuga_Requests
        fields = ['reason']
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Hyuga_Requests(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    s_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add = False)
    e_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add = False)
    reason = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

template

```
<div class='container'>
    <h1> Request Form </h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type='submit'>Submit Request Form</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Help this noobie out please...

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass the properties `s_date` and `e_date` from your model to the model form. In your form you define new fields for `Start_Date` and `End_Date`, but they are not associated with the actual model.

Change your `forms.py` like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm # EDIT: this import is needless
from django.forms.extras import SelectDateWidget

from .models import Hyuga_Requests


class HyugaRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hyuga_Requests
        fields = ('reason', 's_date', 'e_date')
        widgets = {
            's_date': SelectDateWidget(),
            'e_date': SelectDateWidget(),
        }
```

Now you pass the fields `s_date` and `e_date` to the model form and set the widgets for them.

Besides the answer I'd like to point out some bad practices you have introduced in your code. It is about naming conventions, and they are very important.

For class names use the so called PascalCase: `Hyuga_Requests` should be `HyugaRequests`.

Property names of a class are written in snake_case: `Start_Date` isn't good, make it `start_date`. Also `s_date` may be ambigous, write the full name out: `start_date`.

Structure the imports and eventually separate them by blank line. Check how I pulled down the import for the model class.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

If you already use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) on your site and want a powerful **date range picker** you could use [django-bootstrap3-daterangepicker](https://github.com/YuriMalinov/django-bootstrap3-daterangepicker) which is based on [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) and offer tons of customizability and is very well documented.